# summing my data by two specific columns

Tags: r, sum, row

I have my data frame below, I want to sum the data like I have in the first row in the image below (labelled row 38). The total flowering summed for Sections A-D for each date, i also have multiple plots not just Dry1, but Dry2, Dry3 etc.

[image: The data frame]

It's so simple to do in my head but I can't workout how to do it in R?

Essentially I want to do this:

with(dat1, sum(dat1$TotalFlowering[dat1$Date=="1997-07-01" & dat1$Plot=="Dry1"]))

Which tells me that the sum of total flowers for sections "A,B,C,D" in plot "Dry1" for the date "1997-07-01" = 166

I want a way to write a code so this does so for every date and plot combo, and then puts it in the data frame?

In the same format as the first row in the image I included :)

Comment: Can you please add an example of output you're expecting (and also tag your question for R)?

Comment: @Brien edit the title to make it fit, then.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example and also show what you've tried so far. Make sure you conduct a thorough search of stackoverflow in an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: My output I wish for is the First row in the image on my question, the data i have has summed the sections from A-D for the first date but not the others? I wish to sum the total flowering numbers of sections A-D by each specific date and plot. I have been searching for a solutions for quite a while now and have been unable to find it, or at least unable to make it applicable to my particular code. I have tried tapply, apply, sum and mutate. I think it is likely possible with one of those but due to my own ignorance in R i have been unable to work it out :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment it seems like you just want to add a variable to keep track of `TotalFlowering` for every `Date` and `Plot` combination. If that's the case then can you just add a field like `TotalCount` below?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
group_by(Date, Plot) %>%
mutate(TotalCount = sum(TotalFlowering)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Or, alternatively, if all you want is the sum you could make use of `dplyr`'s `summarise` like below

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
group_by(Date, Plot) %>%
summarise(TotalCount = sum(TotalFlowering))
```

Comment: I love you very much sir! Twas the sum that I wanted :)